# DML in HIVE using the Java API

Tags: java, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform, dml, apache-hive

I'm writing an application whitch does DDL and DML in Hive tables. For DDL is use the Hive-Class `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive` which is puplic since Version 1.0. It's perfect for DDL and i think faster than JDBC and other options.

But i couldn't find out how to do DML in JAVA (partitioned and unpartitioned tables). Unfortunatly this Java-API is pretty bad Documented and I couldn't find any example code. How can I do DML without using APIs like JDBC?